# Exporting Access to Macro Enabled Excel

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

does anyone know what is the appropriate excel number to use for macro enabled worksheets?

Specifically: I'm trying to export a table from access to xlsm using this function. Is there a different numeration for the macro enabled workbook?

acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml

Comment: Are you trying to export data to an *existing* .xlsm document? I would have to think so since we can't export Excel macros from Access to a *new* .xlsm file, but it it might be good to [edit] your question in order to clarify.

Comment: Ya I am trying to export data to an existing xlsm

Comment: I just tried `TransferSpreadsheet` with `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` to an existing .xlsm file and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to export data to excel template with formatting and mcroses, do not use DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet method, it just creates Excel file without macroses. Use CopyFromRecordset method of Range object (MS Excel library) instead:

```
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWork = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    Set xlSheet = xlWork.Sheets(strWSName)
    xlSheet.Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rsExportResults
```

Comment: Hey Sergey, where in this code would i declare which Access sheet I want to export, and to which excel sheet?

Comment: strFileName - Excel file name with path,
strWSName - sheet name, 
rsExportResults - recordset with exported data, 
xl* - declared as objects. 
See help for excel library objects for full format